# What is wrong with this URI?

Tags: c#, wpf

Hej

I am trying to load an (embedded) image in a wpf application, using an Uri but I keep getting an exception.

The code is:

```
new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,,/Icons/m.png"));
```

(In case it isn't clear, I am trying to load the m.png file from the Icons folder, which
has been marked as an embedded ressource).

and the exception is

```
NotSupportetException (the URI prefix is not recognized)
```

Can anybody tell me what the uri should have been?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may take a look at [this blog post](http://compilewith.net/2009/03/wpf-unit-testing-trouble-with-pack-uris.html). The solution is to register a custom uri parser so that it recognizes the `pack` protocol:

```
UriParser.Register(
    new GenericUriParser(GenericUriParserOptions.GenericAuthority), "pack", -1
);
```

Comment: In case anyone comes to this page looking for the answer, can you let us know what it was in that post that helped?

Comment: @Foole, this fixes the problem: `UriParser.Register(new GenericUriParser(GenericUriParserOptions.GenericAuthority), "pack", -1)`.

Answer (score 4):

Three commas must be instead of four in your string:

```
new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/LibName;component/Icons/m.png"));
```

LibName - points to assembly where resource is hosted.

Comment: This throws an exception as well.

Comment: I don't think so. If this is a WPF app then it shouldn't throw an exception.

Comment: you are right, it shouldn't but I am not calling this from an WPF class.